# When I try to run a script in my pycharm project I get a error sayng cannot find python.exe file

Tags: python

When I try to open my project I get the following error
"No Python at 'C:\Users\tpottel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe'
 This is the location of an old 32 instantiation, witch has been removed
it is no loner getting it from the the projects
pythonpro/venv/Scripts folder.

I try to set it to (by using settings)
...pythonpro/venv/scripts/python.exe
When I click on ok I get a error saying
Cannot save settings specify a different sdk.

I checked to see if the python.exe file was in the venv/Scripts folder it was.

I try selecting the location from other projects, i still got the same error.

Comment: Are you sure your python installation on `.pythonpro/venv/scripts/python.exe` is not broken? What IDE are you using?

Comment: BTW I see you have a lot of questions where you did not accept the answer. You should accept answers if your issue has been resolved, (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: I.m using pycharm, also thanks for the comment about giving credit.